# Docker solution for mission critical financial apps

Tags: docker

Recently our high management came to think that `Docker` can be a **silver bullet** that can cut cost of apps deployment and especially for our QA testing cycle.

I just started looking into `Docker` solutions and I am in doubt that `Docker` would be a proper fit for our systems.We run a matching engine for major trading app on Linux. So the deployment process is very complex and precise.

Obviously we fight for every microsecond(s) we can save here and there. Would adding an additional layer of 'Docker' access to the kernel add those microseconds to the execution times?

But the major point that bothers me is that they think that it is possible to set up our QA testing lab(s) in `Docker` containers whereas production deployment still be possible to continue the old way, without using `Docker`... They call it "testing just a functionality of the system". Looks improper to me as if apps being set up for `Docker` in QA and tested in QA - so they must be deployed in the same shape and form into production, into `Docker` containers.

Where I should look up advice for a proper solution in such case? Forums/discussion boards?

Thanks in advance for any piece of advice.

Comment: If you were really working on a "mission critical" app then why are you worried about "cutting costs"?

Comment: I am NOT the one who makes the decisions of such magnitude. Where and how cost to be cut. Often at the high level of management decisions are made based not on the best interest of the business in the long run but just to fulfill short term financial goals. World is not a perfect C++ library...

Answer (score 1):

A few thoughts:

- The use of Dockerfiles gives you fine-grained control over the configuration of the processing environment in which your application(s) will run. You can rest assured that your application runtime environment will be consistent across your deployment target machines.
- The layered approach of successively building Docker images on top of other images gives you flexibility and efficiency during deployment. Only rebuild/redeploy what is needed.
- Multiple containers can run on the same machine using the same images. This beats the processor-intensive use of multiple VM’s.
- Docker contaniers are ideal for QA, system testing, etc precisely *because* of the predictibility of the envirnoment in which your application runs. How do you know now that the QA you do exactly matches the runtime environment when deployed?
- It is very easy to spin up containers running different flavors of Linux. This aids your testing on differnt OS’s
- Test the execution time! These are *not* VM’s and the benefits of containers may outweigh a loss of a few mircoseconds. Or maybe not. Only one way to really know.

We are very pleased with our use of Docker containers - we deliver containers to our customers, we use them for continous integration testing, etc. It beats dealing with others mucking directly with the conguration of our Linux boxes and then wondering why things are or are not working now.